# Markov Chain: Stationary distribution variance

Tags: markov-chains, variance

Suppose to consider a generic Markov Chain, suppose $P$ to be the unknown transition matrix and $\pi$ its stationary distribution.

Assume $Var[P]$ to be known (estimated from some data).

(Variance is calculated element-wise)

We know that:

$\pi = \pi P$

I'm interested in $Var[\pi]$, the main problem I'm facing is the lack of independence between $\pi$ and $P$.

Some help? Thank you!